# Using another project in a service

Tags: c#, exception, service

I've tried since yesterday to make my service work, but I haven't found a solution, so I'm forced to ask for your help.
I simplified classes to only focus on the problem.

My service:

```
using test_import;

namespace Hespéride
{
public partial class Hespéride : ServiceBase
{
    private Timer timer = null;

    public Hespéride()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        Debugger.Launch();
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 60000; // 60 seconds  
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimer);
        timer.Start();
        OnTimer(null, null);
    }

    public void OnTimer(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs args)
    {
        try
        {
            Voiture v = new Voiture(2);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            eventLog1.WriteEntry(e.Message);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        timer.Stop();
    }
}
}
```

I also have another existing project, `test_import`, that contains my class `Voiture` which I tried to use. 
I added the project `test_import` to the solution (right click solution > add > existing project > `test_import.csproj`), and then added the references in the service project `Hespéride` (right click references > add reference > project > `test_import`)

[image]
[image]

But when I try to run my service and debug it (I've attached the debugger of visual studio to the process), it keeps stopping and sending me this exception :

> Service cannot be started. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not
>   load file or assembly 'test_import, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot
>   find the file specified. File name: 'test_import, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' at
>   Hespéride.Hespéride.OnTimer(Object sender, ElapsedEventArgs args) at
>   Hespéride.Hespéride.OnStart(String[] args) in
>   C:\Users\jpougetoux\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\Hespéride\Hespéride\Hespéride.cs:ligne 26 at
>   System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.ServiceQueuedMainCallback(Object
>   state)

On the other hand, when I put the code in `OnTimer` into the main of the `program.cs` of my service `Hespéride`, it works perfectly and there is no errors on import.

Someone suggested to me that I need to add the `dll` in the service installation folder, but I don't have a `dll` since `test_project` is not a library.
I could compile `test_project` as a `dll`, but then will it be possible to modify it later or should I need to compile and re-import it after every modification ?

So if someone has a solution, or a tutorial that explains well how to do that, I'd be very thankful.

Comment: if you click on the reference, and then check its path and that it points to the right location? I'm assuming test_imports is a console application, which should be no problem as exe can be in the path name.

Comment: Yes it pointed on the right location. I did the project again by following a tuto and it work, i don't understand why and how but there is no erreur anymore..